# Xcode 14.0 Crashes when Opening Storyboard Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit, xcode14

Xcode 14.0 crashes when I open my Main.storyboard. It happens randomly but especially anytime i go back to it from another code file window or other storyboard.

Any advice would be really appreciated. I have attempted cleaning build folder, restarting, fixing constraints, setting useAutolayout="YES" to NO...

Nothing seem to work and at this point it crashes so often that I can not even investigate the interface builder that much.
What might be way to narrow in on what is the root cause of the crashing?

The report shows that 'Thread 13 crashes' but i am unsure what to do to prevent that.

```
    -------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               Xcode [14057]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               14.0 (21335)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-21335000000000000~35 (14A309)
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       851890269
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2022-09-25 16:54:25.9759 -0600
OS Version:            macOS 12.6 (21G115)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     6.6 (19P6067)
Anonymous UUID:        5350E89D-B390-D37F-76F9-598FD667385E

Sleep/Wake UUID:       6D902654-A522-4A2E-87D3-D3F577604736

Time Awake Since Boot: 5900 seconds
Time Since Wake:       5046 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        13  Dispatch queue: Xcode.IB.MessageChannel

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
com.apple.main-thread


Application Specific Signatures:
!previousCommandBacktrace
...
Thread 13 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: Xcode.IB.MessageChannel
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff80af6400e __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80af9a1ff pthread_kill + 263
2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x7ff80aee5d24 abort + 123
3   IDEKit                                 0x109a9f307 +[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:assertionSignature:assertionReason:extraBacktrace:] + 1216
4   IDEKit                                 0x109a9f812 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] + 1075
5   DVTFoundation                          0x10650e4b5 _DVTAssertionHandler + 464
6   DVTFoundation                          0x10650e6c1 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler + 306
7   AssetCatalogFoundation                 0x11846d945 -[IBMessageSendChannel sendMessage:returnValue:context:error:arguments:] + 1785
8   IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration           0x12da2ab36 __61-[IBCocoaTouchToolProxy updateScenesWithSceneUpdateRequests:]_block_invoke + 115
9   IDEInterfaceBuilderKit                 0x12c7bb9ef -[IBAbstractPlatformToolProxy _ON_QUEUE_sendMessage:toChannelReturningError:during:] + 149
10  IDEInterfaceBuilderKit                 0x12c7bb636 __59-[IBAbstractPlatformToolProxy sendMessage:toChannelDuring:]_block_invoke + 49
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80ade3317 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80adf07ee _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 60
13  DVTFoundation                          0x10655d1bb DVTDispatchSync + 148
14  IDEInterfaceBuilderKit                 0x12c7bb550 -[IBAbstractPlatformToolProxy sendMessage:toChannelDuring:] + 217
15  IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration           0x12da2aa90 -[IBCocoaTouchToolProxy updateScenesWithSceneUpdateRequests:] + 123
16  IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration           0x12da45b6c __114-[IBCocoaTouchSceneUpdateRequestProcessor performRequestOnBackgroundThreadWithData:diagnosticsBlock:platformTool:]_block_invoke.33 + 30
17  IDEInterfaceBuilderKit                 0x12ca675b9 +[IBPlatformToolFailureHandler performRequestWithTool:failureHandlerBlock:failureMessageBlock:diagnosticsConfigurationBlock:duringBlock:] + 114
18  IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration           0x12da4557f -[IBCocoaTouchSceneUpdateRequestProcessor performRequestOnBackgroundThreadWithData:diagnosticsBlock:platformTool:] + 413
19  IDEInterfaceBuilderKit                 0x12ca6b5ce __42-[IBPlatformToolRequester processRequests]_block_invoke + 740
20  IDEInterfaceBuilderKit                 0x12ca6a72b -[IBPlatformToolRequester _connectToToolProxyWithSupersessionIdentifier:during:] + 802
21  IDEInterfaceBuilderKit                 0x12ca6b0c2 -[IBPlatformToolRequester processRequests] + 1102
22  IDEInterfaceBuilderKit                 0x12ca69a2d __104-[IBPlatformToolRequester issueRequestWithData:supersessionIdentifier:diagnosticsBlock:completionBlock:]_block_invoke + 21
23  DVTFoundation                          0x10655c789 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
24  DVTFoundation                          0x10655d29d __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 196
25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80ade20cc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
26  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80ade3317 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
27  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80ade9317 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 672
28  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80ade9dfd _dispatch_lane_invoke + 366
29  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80adf3eee _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 753
30  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80af96fd0 _pthread_wqthread + 326
31  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80af95f57 start_wqthread + 15
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the folder where the storyboard is located and then right click -> open with -> Xcode. it will open. The project should already be open in Xcode so the storyboard will open in the same project.